# how to avoid overriding the file from merged branch in git

Tags: git, file, merge, overriding

We have three branches as master, develop and release. We made some changes in release branch's file and tried to merge with developer but what happened.

we have test.html in both the branches as developer and release and we lost all the develop branch's file content after merging with release. I would like to know what caused this.
I used below commands:

```
>git checkout release
>git checkout develop
>git merge release
```

no conflict but lost develop branch file content. this is very strange to me. never happened before.

I tried to merge with cherry-pick and specific file merge also but nothing workout all these commands are overriding develop branch file content.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the problem without a log. If the merge was done without a conflict, it possibly was a fast-forward merge. This might happen if `release` was a child of `develop`'s head commit.

Also, the above commands merge `release` into `develop`. Is that what you meant?

Please run the following command and post results here:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Comment: Please find the log of before and after:                                                https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Ugo4XSON8HbW1KeFRWeHk3VlU/view?usp=sharing